# how to find absolute touch point on screen at android

Tags: android, position, touch, ontouchlistener, absolute

I've read several topics around this issue and I'm surprised there is no smth about *absolute* touch point position.

I touch some views on a screen, these views don't know whether they are on the top of screen, middle or bottom. 
So the usual code like:

```
switch (event.getAction()){
     case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
     startY = event.getY();
}
```

will be irrelevant because it can show me only 'y' point inside that view I touched. But i want to know where i touched my screen absolutely, independently to that specific view.

In my case, it is enough to know whether I touch screen at its top, middle or bottom so I can roughly divide the screen to smth like:

```
getHeight(getWindowManager()/3)
```

and check which part I am inside.

Comment: Have a look at the `getRawX()` and `getRawY()` methods of [`MotionEvent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html).

Comment: yes you are right, getRawY() made my day